i am having problem on creating bottomNavigationView related to height, the height is doubled as i expected even when the height is set to wrap
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/primary"
    app:itemIconSize="20dp"
    app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Active"
    app:itemTextAppearanceInactive="@style/BottomNavigationView.Inactive"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"/>

enter image description here
i am expecting default height of the bottom navigation view.

I don't know if it is the solution that you are waiting, but I solved this deleting next piece of code on my Activity.kt:
enableEdgeToEdge()

and
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
        val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
        insets
    }

Another way is changing
setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)

for
setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, 0)


It worked !! Thank You Brother ...

If you are using this in an Activity then, remove these following lines form the onCreate() method,
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
    val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
    insets
}

And Add this following lines
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
    val params = binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    params.bottomMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
    binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams = params
    insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
}

And If you are using it in a fragment then, remove these following lines form the onCreate() method of the host activity,
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
    val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
    insets
}

And add this following lines to the onViewCreated() method of the fragment
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(view) { v, insets ->
    val params = binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
    params.bottomMargin = insets.systemWindowInsetBottom
    binding.bottomNavigationView.layoutParams = params
    insets.consumeSystemWindowInsets()
}

this will solve the extra space issue.
